# Passing array of objects int jQuery .data() attributeto list<T>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a array of objects that are of a type ProductField.  I am passing it using JQuery to a WebMethod that is setup to accept the data.

The call is made as below:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ProductNumber: ProductInfo.ProductNumber, ProductFieldList: ProductInfo.ProductFieldList.ProductFields, IsPreSelected: ispreselected }),
```

and the web method is below:

```
[WebMethod]

public static object AddCandidateSolution(string ProductNumber, List<ProductField> ProductFieldList, bool IsPreSelected)
```

if you use fiddler you can see that the data is being sent over

```
{
  "ProductNumber": "INS_00005",
  "ProductFieldList": [
    {
      "__type": "Datastructure.BaseClasses.ProductField",
      "ProductFieldID": 1,
      "ProductTypeID": 4,
      "Name": "State",
      "Prompt": "Drivers License State:",
      "DataTypeID": 5,
      "Required": true,
      "MinLength": 2,
      "MaxLength": 2,
      "Validation": "fn_isValidState(1)",
      "Visible": true,
      "Value": "NC",
      "DefaultValue": ""
    },
    {
      "__type": "Datastructure.BaseClasses.ProductField",
      "ProductFieldID": 3,
      "ProductTypeID": 4,
      "Name": "License",
      "Prompt": "Drivers License Number:",
      "DataTypeID": 3,
      "Required": true,
      "MinLength": 0,
      "MaxLength": 0,
      "Validation": "Utility.ufn_Validate_DriversLicenseFormat(1,3)",
      "Visible": true,
      "Value": "9951847",
      "DefaultValue": ""
    },
    {
      "__type": "Datastructure.BaseClasses.ProductField",
      "ProductFieldID": 4,
      "ProductTypeID": 4,
      "Name": "Term",
      "Prompt": "Drivers License Term:",
      "DataTypeID": 5,
      "Required": true,
      "MinLength": 1,
      "MaxLength": 1,
      "Validation": "fn_isValidDriversTerm(1,4)",
      "Visible": true,
      "Value": "3Y",
      "DefaultValue": ""
    }
  ],
  "IsPreSelected": "false"
}
```

However my issue is that when I am in the WebMethod, the values for ProductNumber and IsPreSelected are being set, but the List is set to a size of 3 but the data is not being filled in.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Can webmethods automagically bind parameter lists from json post data?

Comment: It has been done in another project with different classes by a previous developer but I cannot replicate it in this one. There was a function after is but I don't know what it was doing.

Comment: This is the previous on that worked data: JSON.stringify({ ProductFieldList: ServiceInfo, IsPreselected: ispreselected }, function (k, v) { return v === "" ? "" : v }),

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.  My class had {get; private set}.  Once I removed the private set and replaced with set, it worked fine.